# Regular Expressions inline options

Tags: php, regex

I have a text that has the possible values already in the text, i want to show the right values in situations. I'm not really good with regexes and i don't really know how to explain my problem so here is an example. I've got it working almost:

```
$string = "This [was a|is the] test!";

preg_replace('/\[(.*)\|(.*)\]/', '$1', $string);
// results in "This was a text!"

preg_replace('/\[(.*)\|(.*)\]/', '$2', $string);
// results in "This is the test!"
```

This works without problems but when there are two parts it doesn't work anymore because it gets the end bracket from the last.

```
$string = "This [was a|is the] so this is [bullshit|filler] text";

preg_replace('/\[(.*)\|(.*)\]/', '$1', $string);
//results in "This was a|is the] test so this is [bullshit text"

preg_replace('/\[(.*)\|(.*)\]/', '$2', $string);
//results in "This filler text"
```

Situation 1 should be the values between ( and | and situation 2 should show the values between | and ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your probem is the regex [greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#~Watch+Out+for+The+Greediness). Add a `?` after `.*` to make it consume only the string within the square brackets:

```
 preg_replace('/\[(.*?)\|(.*?)\]/', '$1', $string);
```

Likewise could you use the `/U` ungreedy modifier. Better yet use a more specific match in place of `.*?` anything.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using:

```
(.*)
```

...to match the stuff inside of the options groups, use this:

```
([^|\]]*)
```

That pattern matches anything that is not a | or a ], repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

You can forbid `|` characters in your `.*` replacing the `.` with `[^|]` (which means “no `|`”).

```
$string = "This [was a|is the] so this is [bullshit|filler] text";

echo preg_replace('/\[([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\]/', '$1', $string);
// results in "This was a so this is bullshit text"

echo '<br />';

echo preg_replace('/\[([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\]/', '$2', $string);
// results in "This is the so this is filler text"
```